# Can Kobo read Hebrew ePubs?

Tags: kobo, fonts, language

I noticed Kobo eReader does not have Hebrew in pre-installed languages. Can kobo read Hebrew ePub properly?

Comment: Do you mean, read only, or also display (which would be more useful IMO)?

Comment: I have a 1st gen Kobo Glo, if there is some freely available book that I can download somewhere I can test this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Kobo eReaders have two reading engines:

1. Adobe RMSDK (epub2)
2. ACCESS NetFront (epub3)

The ACCESS NetFront epub3 engine supports RTL text in epub3 books with a .kepub extension. Depending on the model/firmware, you might have to embed/install Hebrew fonts. For more information also see this [website](https://github.com/kobolabs/epub-spec#epub-versions-kobo-supports).

You also might want to check out the [Mobileread Kobo](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=275196) forum for more detailed information.

**tl;dr** The answer is yes, but you'll most likely have to convert epub2 books to epub3 books and change the file extension to .kepub. (You also might have to embed/install Hebrew fonts.)